# .Net Regex match for a browser agent version?

Tags: .net, regex, match

Looking for a browser agent regex to match the OS version, I have the following as test cases:

```
Apple~iPad~iOS~7~Mobile Safari~7.0"); << should match
Apple~iPad~iOS~7.12~Mobile Safari~7.0"); << should match
Apple~iPad~iOS~7.12.45~Mobile Safari~7.0"); << should match
Apple~iPad~iOS~7.99.451.987~Mobile Safari~7.0") << should match
Apple~iPad~iOS~blah~Mobile Safari~7.0"); << should NOT match
Apple~iPad~iOS~~Mobile Safari~7.0"); << should NOT match
Apple~iPad~iOS~7.XXXX~Mobile Safari~7.0"); << should NOT match
```

This gets me in the vicinity, but the last ones comes through as match on iOS~7 when it shouldn't:

```
iOS~(\d+)(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?
```

What is the correct regex for matching desired results here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw a `(?!\.\D)` in there:

```
iOS~(\d+)(?!\.\D)(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?
```

[regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/pJ2xM7/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about negative look ahead of `(?!\.X)` like : `iOS~(\d+)(?!\.X)(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?`

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vZ4cP6/1)

Or you could use `(?!\.\D)` to match anything that is not a number

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead,

```
iOS~(\d+)(?:(\.\d+)+)?(?!\.)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yA5fA2/1)

If you want to capture the numbers in groups, then  use this

```
iOS~(\d+)(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(?!\.)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vZ4cP6/2)

**OR**

You could use a positive lookahead also,

```
iOS~(\d+)(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?(?=~)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vZ4cP6/3)